# Self-adjoint differential operators

Tags: mathematical-physics, operators, hilbert-space

I'm having a hard time understanding the deal with [self-adjoint differential opertors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator)  used to solve a set of two coupled 2nd order PDEs.

The thing is, that the solution of the PDEs becomes numerically unstable and I've heared that this is due to the fact, that the used operators were not self-adjoint and the energy is not preserved in this case.

The two coupled 2nd order PDEs are:

$$\frac{\partial ^2p}{\partial t^2}=V_{px}^2 {H_2} p + \alpha V_{pz}^2 {H_1} q + V_{sz}^2{H_1}(p - \alpha q) + S\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{\partial ^2q}{\partial t^2}=\frac{V_{pn}^2}{\alpha}{H_2} p + V_{pz}^2 {H_1} q - V_{sz}^2{H_2} \left(\frac{1}{\alpha}p - q \right) + S\tag{2}$$

where p is the pressure wave field and q is an auxiliary wave field, $S$ is the Source term $V_{px}$ and $V_{sz}$ are seismic velocities into the x - or z-direction respectively, $\alpha = 1$ and $H_1$ and $H_2$ are the rotated differential operators:
\begin{eqnarray}
{H_1}& =& \sin ^2 \theta \cos ^2 \phi \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x ^2}+\sin ^2 \theta \sin ^2 \phi \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y ^2} + \cos ^2 \theta \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial z ^2}+\\ &&\sin ^2 \theta \sin 2 \phi \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial z} + \sin 2 \theta \sin \phi \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial y}+ \sin 2 \theta \cos \phi \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial y}\end{eqnarray}

$$
{H_2} = \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x ^2}+\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y ^2}+\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial z ^2} - {H_1}.
$$

where $\phi$ is an azimuth angle and $\theta$ is a tilt angle.

In this case I am solving for the solution of a pressure wavefield.

**EDIT**
Is there a physical explanation for self-adjoint operators?
The paper I am referring to can be found [here](http://www.cgg.com/technicalDocuments/cggv_0000009953.pdf) were equation 14 and 15 resemble my postet equations.

Comment: You should be much more precise both mathematically and physically. It is impossible to understand (and help you) otherwise.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/677772/11127 and to http://mathoverflow.net/q/157685/13917 . In general, it is frown upon to cross-post simultaneously, because it may waste potential answerer's time. As a minimum OP should mention the cross-post (on both sites!). The preferred procedure is to not cross-post, and if the post hasn't received an acceptable answer after, say, a couple of days, then OP could flag for migration.

Comment: yes it is a cross post since they mentioned, that this question would get answered more likely in this forum. I am going to delete the question which does not get the answer at the end

Comment: The thing I don t understand is more general: Is there a physical explanation for self-adjoint differential operators?

Comment: Could you write what coupled PDE you're solving ([you can use MathJax](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) here)?

Comment: Barring the mathematical meaning, self-adjointness could mean several things in physics. It depends on the context. I really do not understand your question. *What are you asking*?

Comment: I do not understand what happens physically if differential operators are not self-adjoint.

Comment: Another question: Why are you mixing spherical & Cartesian coordinates? This is formally an [elliptic PDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation). It seems to me that you'd need to save your $f(t-dt)$ as well as your $f(t)$ data to use a [finite difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method) method, but other methods (that I'm not familiar with) could exist, I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: @Kyle This is due to the fact, that I describe a rotated symmetry in a cartesian coordinate system. I posted the link to the paper I am referring to[link](http://www.cgg.com/technicalDocuments/cggv_0000009953.pdf) were equation 14 and equation  15 are equivalent to my PDEs. In equation 20 they rotate the coordinate system and claim, that the rotated operators have to be self-adjoint and non-positive for stability. maybe this is formulated clearer...

Answer (score 5):

I do not know it this is an answer, since I am not sure to have understood your question. The structure of the equation is formally hyperbolic:
$$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} - A\psi = S\quad (1)$$
where $\psi =(p,q)^t$. 
If $A$ were self-adjoint and non-negative (or non positive, changing a sign and inserting a further $i$ in front of $\sqrt{-A}$ as I say below), one would construct another self-adjoint operator $\sqrt{A}$ using the spectral theory, and (1) would be re-written as:
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - \sqrt{A} \right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \sqrt{A} \right)\psi(t) = S(t)\:.\quad (2)$$
This equation can be solved interpreting the derivative as a derivative in the strong operator topology in the Hilbert space of the theory. The solution $\psi=\psi(t)$ is a map valued in the said Hilbert space. So for every fixed $t$, in your case, $\psi(t)= \psi(t|\vec{x})$ is an element $L^2(\mathbb R^3)\oplus L^2(\mathbb R^3)$ or some associated Sobolev space. Then one should prove that these solutions are also solutions in proper sense.
Equation (2) has a canonical solution, in the said sense, obtained iterating the solution of 
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \pm  \sqrt{A} \right) \Phi(t) = Z(t)$$
which is:
$$\Phi(t) = \Phi(0) + e^{\mp t\sqrt{A}}\int_0^t e^{\pm \tau\sqrt{A}} Z(\tau) d\tau\:.$$ 
Iteration introduces the first derivative $\partial_t \psi(0)$ as second initial datum, together with $\psi(0)$. The solution of (2) eventually depends on those initial data.

There are however problems with the domains of the involved operators, in general, especially because $e^{t\sqrt{A}}$ is not bounded for $t>0$.

If $A$ is self-adjoint and non-positive, $-A$ is non-negative and thus (2) can be re-written as:
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - i\sqrt{-A} \right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + i\sqrt{-A} \right)\psi(t) = S(t)\:,\quad (3)$$
and the solution can be obtained referring to 
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \pm  i\sqrt{-A} \right) \Phi(t) = Z(t)$$
which solves as:
$$\Phi(t) = \Phi(0) + e^{\mp it\sqrt{-A}}\int_0^t e^{\pm i\tau\sqrt{-A}} Z(\tau) d\tau\:.$$

The situation with domains here improves because $e^{it\sqrt{-A}}$ is bounded (is unitary) for every $t \in \mathbb R$ and thus its domain is the whole Hilbert space.

If $A$ is not self-adjoint what I wrote above does not apply form scratch since $\sqrt{\pm A}$ is not well-defined (it could still be if $A$ were normal).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I tried to undesrstand what you did: a) you constructed a self-adjoint operator, b) you gave the solution for $\psi$ which is not bounded for t > 0 if the operators are not bounded? unfortunately I did not get the last part with $e^{it\sqrt{-A}}$. were do you get this from or is it a typo?

Comment: The solution, constructed as I showed could not exists if $S$ does not belong to the right domain. I am completing my answer including the case $i\sqrt{-A}$

Comment: I stay in Europe, here is getting quite late, I should sleep! Tomorrow I will be back if necessary. Bye

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help! unfortunately I am no mathematician and it is quite difficult for me transferring your answer to my problem. So the PDEs form a wave equation of acoustic waves in a medium. S is a source function that produces the initial pressure anomaly which travels through the medium. Now, with the operators given, the amplitudes grow exponentially over time. so I assumed, that the problem was inherent to the diff. operators. as people state, that this was because they were not self-adjoined, I came up with this question. is your answer transferable to my problem?

Comment: Can you find normal modes of your operators $H$? Is there another way to write down $H_1$? To understand its physical origin. Why polar coordinates?

Comment: The paper I am referring to can be found here: [link](http://www.cgg.com/technicalDocuments/cggv_0000009953.pdf) Maybe this is the easiest way to explain even though it is not very elegant, I am sorry. Equation 14 and equation 15 in this paper is equivalent to my given PDEs. In equation 20 they rotate the coordinate system and claim, that the rotated operators have to be self-adjoint and non-positive in order to achieve stability. That is the part I do not understand...

Comment: unfortunately these are not my derived operators and I do not have the mathemtical background to rewrite them. by normal modes you mean, that the eigenvectors are perpendicular to each other?